# How to show $x^{p}-5$ is irreducible over $\displaystyle\mathbb{Q}(\exp(\frac{i2\pi}{p}))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If I use $\omega_{p}=\exp(\frac{i2\pi}{p})$, then because $x^{p}-5=(x-\sqrt[p]{5})(x-\sqrt[p]{5}\omega_{p})(x-\sqrt[p]{5}\omega_{p}^{2})\cdots(x-\sqrt[p]{5}\omega_{p}^{p-1})$, if this splits into two factors in $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{p})$, then from the constant terms of the factors, $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{p})$ would have to contain $5^{\frac{a}{p}}$, $1\leq a<p$. I hoped  $5^{\frac{a}{p}}\notin\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{p})$, because this is what I've been doing to show some polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$, but I couldn't figure out how to show this in $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{p})$, or I'm not sure if this would work here. Please let me know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: 
(I assume that $p$ is a prime here.)
If you show that the splitting field $K$ of $x^p-5$ contains $\omega_p$, then you can look at the degree of the extensions $K/ \mathbb{Q}$ and $K/\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$.

Degree of  the first extension is divisible by $p$ since $x^p-5$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ but the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)/\mathbb{Q}$ is not.
Now, you need to think if $p$ can divide the degree of $K/\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$ if $x^p-5$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$.